# How to publish a new plugin in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I just created a new plugin for ckeditor, 
But when I login, I see the plugin under "[MathEx](http://ckeditor.com/addon/MathEx)", which is marked as "unpublished".

Help me to resolve this with your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Your release failed validation, that's why it wasn't published.

To avoid those errors and waiting in the future releases I'm proposing to do similar check we do on our side before adding new releases.

We're using our builder for this: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckbuilder

Example command you can run to perform the check:

`/usr/bin/java -jar ckbuilder.jar --no-ie-checks --verify-plugin your_plugin_1.0.zip`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you simply didn't yet publish any release using "Add new plugin version" button?

[image]

Comment: already done that process and i'm getting this message
Pending release : 1.1
Your release will be published in the next few minutes.